# Erro ao compilar projeto no QT Creator

Tags: c++, qt

Estou querendo seriamente estudar programação e eu escolhi a framework QT, quando eu estava com um *dualboot* no meu computador não havia este problema que eu estou tendo agora depois de remover o *dualboot* e instalar so o Ubuntu 14.10.

No Ubuntu instalou o QT sem problema e na hora de compilar o projeto o QT Creator está a me dar o erro abaixo. Como resolver este problema?

```
04:49:43: Running steps for project untitled1...
04:49:43: Starting: "/home/tandavala/Qt/5.3/gcc/bin/qmake" /home/tandavala/untitled1/untitled1.pro -r -spec linux-g++ CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=declarative_debug CONFIG+=qml_debug
04:49:43: The process "/home/tandavala/Qt/5.3/gcc/bin/qmake" exited normally.
04:49:43: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
g++ -c -pipe -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_QUICK_LIB -DQT_QML_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../Qt/5.3/gcc/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I../untitled1 -I../Qt/5.3/gcc/include -I../Qt/5.3/gcc/include/QtQuick -I../Qt/5.3/gcc/include/QtQml -I../Qt/5.3/gcc/include/QtWidgets -I../Qt/5.3/gcc/include/QtNetwork -I../Qt/5.3/gcc/include/QtGui -I../Qt/5.3/gcc/include/QtCore -I. -I. -o main.o ../untitled1/main.cpp
/home/tandavala/Qt/5.3/gcc/bin/rcc -name qml ../untitled1/qml.qrc -o qrc_qml.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_QUICK_LIB -DQT_QML_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../Qt/5.3/gcc/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I../untitled1 -I../Qt/5.3/gcc/include -I../Qt/5.3/gcc/include/QtQuick -I../Qt/5.3/gcc/include/QtQml -I../Qt/5.3/gcc/include/QtWidgets -I../Qt/5.3/gcc/include/QtNetwork -I../Qt/5.3/gcc/include/QtGui -I../Qt/5.3/gcc/include/QtCore -I. -I. -o qrc_qml.o qrc_qml.cpp
g++ -Wl,-rpath,/home/tandavala/Qt/5.3/gcc -Wl,-rpath,/home/tandavala/Qt/5.3/gcc/lib -o untitled1 main.o qrc_qml.o   -L/home/tandavala/Qt/5.3/gcc/lib -lQt5Quick -lQt5Qml -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Network -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:192: recipe for target 'untitled1' failed
make: *** [untitled1] Error 1
04:49:47: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project untitled1 (kit: Desktop Qt 5.3 GCC 32bit)
When executing step "Make"
04:49:47: Elapsed time: 00:05.
```

Comment: Basicamente o seu erro é o `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL`.

Answer (score 2):

Logico este e o problema amigo, sabes mais com um pouco de pesquisa consegui resolver so era digitar no terminal sudo `sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev`
e o problema estara resolvido

Answer (score 0):

O seu erro basicamente é este:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
```

[Neste link](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/23855), eu achei a seguinte dica:

```
sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev -y
```

Outra dica que achei [neste outro link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1480282). Dê uma olhada na pasta `/usr/lib` e veja se o `libGL.so` está lá. Se estiver, mas com um nome diferente, você pode fazer isso:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libGL.so.xx.xx.xx /usr/lib/libGL.so
```

[Em uma pergunta no StackOverflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057737/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lgl-nvidia-lubuntu-12-10), alguém teve o mesmo problema que você e conseguiu resolver. No caso dele, as bibliotecas estavam na pasta `/usr/lib/nvidia-current`, então para resolver, a resposta aceita de lá sugere algo mais ou menos assim:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/nvidia-current/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/libGL.so.1
sudo ln -s /usr/lib32/nvidia-current/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/libGL.so.1
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/nvidia-current/libGL.so /usr/lib/libGL.so
sudo ln -s /usr/lib32/nvidia-current/libGL.so /usr/lib/libGL.so
```

Talvez isso resolva.